# Optimize Android 2.3 on hardware without graphic acceleration

Tags: android, rendering, surfaceflinger

I have some arm-based device with Android 2.3.
Unfortunately there is no graphic acceleration, so compositing of final image in surface flinger is done using software opengl - and this is really slow.

The main problem is with glDrawArrays method (called in LayerBase::drawWithOpenGl).
I checked that glDrawTexiOES is much faster than glDrawArrays but I can't use it (it doesn't support 90 degree rotation).

So I'm looking for any idea which can improves my rendering. I was trying to implement custom method for fast blitting with rotation by 90 degrees but I'm not sure how to get pointer to source and destination memory to do it. Do you have any other ideas?